# chrome extension manifest V3 - how to clear storage on specific tab close?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webapi

I have a bit of complicated chrome extension which it's task is to scrape an HTML table that spans over multiple pages, each page is backend-rendered.

Thanks to the extension mechanics, I can store the table data in `storage.local`, and once the extension auto-paging to the next page, the extension adds up its table data.

So far it works like a charm, but the problems starting once I close the tab where the table is. The final goal is to clear the table data storage object only when the user closing the **exact same tab** where the **scraping** was active.

So far I've tried the following approaches:

`chrome.tabs.onRemoved` - [as described here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onRemoved), doesn't work - it activates on **every** closing tab, what I'm not interested in. I cannot catch the active tab before it closing because the chrome already unloaded the tab and the active becomes the one I just moved into.

`window.onbeforeunload` or `window.unload` also doesn't work - it triggers every time the page is refreshing or moving to the next table page (remember - it's a backend rendered table, table with multiple pages triggering the unload with every page change)

**My question is** - How can I clear the storage once user shuts down the specific tab the **scraper** was working at?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onRemoved and compare the reported tab id to the one you're using.

Comment: @wOxxOm but how can I know that the one I'm using matching to the scrapper?
Now when I query for active tab, it getting me the one chrome moved me to, not the one I just closed. I cannot tell if I closed other tab or the specific scrapper tab.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__, __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapping or scrapper

Comment: The exact call depends on how you create/use that tab, there are several methods, but it's usually trivial.